# how to convert the number of days of year into Date in salesforce

Tags: date, conversion

```
I'm stuck with a requirement here.
I have a Julian date of the format "115090".
Here.. 1 - denotes the century i.e 20th Century. 
15 - denotes the year of the century i.e. 2015. 
(Until this part I'm able to convert the YEAR part of the Standard Salesforce DATE) 
090 - denotes the NUMBER of days for the year 2015. 
(090 - 31 days of Jan + 28 Days of FEB + 31 Days of Mar)
So , Typically 115090 should return 31-MAR-2015 or 31/03/2015. 

All I'm able to get is the YEAR of the DATE 

IF(
   BEGINS(Alert_Date__c , "1"),
   2000 + VALUE(MID(Alert_Date__c,2,2)),NULL
)


I'm Not able to convert the number of days of the year i.e. 090 to 31/03.
If am not wrong , in no. of days, i have to check for LEAP year as well.
please provide some assistance.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know the year so can create a [DATE](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&language=en_US#DATE) for Jan 1st and then add your day offset. Using your example you would create the date using `DATE(2015, 1, 1)` and then add 89 (90 - 1) days.

```
DATE(theYear, 1, 1) + (numberOfDays - 1)
```

You don't need to handle leap years using this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I did some work around and ruff code which will help you out - Call one method having this code and get your date -----
User proper variables place to place- which I didn't did because of time.

```
year=YOU GOT IT;

if(mydate < 31){
    month=1;  //January
    for(i=0;i< mydate; i++){
         day=day+1; 
                  }
}else if(mydate < 59){
                // 31 + 28  = 59   ---- i.e. January + Feb day 
    // Use your logic here to handle Leap Years (divide by 4,100,400) and work around.

    month=2;  //Feb
    mydate=mydate-31;  // Subtract the No.of days of previous all months
    for(i=0;i< mydate; i++){
         day=day+1; 
    }
}else if(mydate < 31){ 
                // 31 + 28  = 59 + 31 = 90   ---- i.e. January + Feb + March 

    month=3;  //March
    mydate=mydate-59;  // Subtract the No.of days of previous all months -- Jan + Feb = 59 days
    for(i=0;i< mydate; i++){
         day=day+1; 
    }
}
```

Let me know if this found useful to you, Do Cudo's too.

Comment: Thanks for your help !! I Had to bring this into a formula field. and BarCotter solution made it work !!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help , This is what i did !!

```
DATE(
IF(
BEGINS(Alert_Date__c , "1"),
2000 + VALUE(MID(Alert_Date__c,2,2)),
IF(
BEGINS(Alert_Date__c , "0"),
1900 + VALUE(MID(Alert_Date__c,2,2)),
NULL
)
),1,1)
+
(
VALUE(TRIM(RIGHT(Alert_Date__c,3))) - 1
)
```

Now its working fine.

Comment: Another way to do the year would be `1900 + (100 x VALUE(LEFT(Alert_Date__c, 1))`, which removes the need to have the IF cases and will support all the centuries in the future even if your software doesn't last that long :-)

Comment: Cool ! Surely Salesforce will exist in the next century too :D